# Access all installed applications database in Android

Tags: android, operating-system

I want to access all installed applications database and other internal files from my application, which I will be building along with my custom Android OS.
I am not able to figure out, how to achieve this task.

I have tried by modifying run-as.c so that it works for non debuggable applications. Now the problem I am facing is, it is working from command prompt but if I try to run it from my application, I am getting "Permission Denied". Also from command prompt, I am able to pull the db from data/data/<package name>/databases, reverse is not working.

Any kind of suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to access that information because they are stored in a secured location. Maybe if your device is rooted?

Comment: In my case, I am building my custom OS. So is it possible to add some extra class which I can call from my application to achieve this task?